# Round layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create custom `Button` with drawable as background and set round corners on it :

1) Set the layout background (a drawable)

2) Add round corner to the drawable

3) Add drawable to layout

Problems are :

1) I can't use `onDraw()` method.

2) I can't use this code (in order to DON'T replace the current background):
    mylayaout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_left_right));

So, is there a way to get the current background drawable, set round corner on it and set it as background ?

I hope I am clear.

Thanks.

Comment: `I hope I am clear.` not so much. I understood you don't like onDraw (I also avoid doing in code what I can comfortably do in xml). But I don't understand if you don't want to use an xml drawable? The only alternative I can think of then is using a PNG... And this wouldn't be an optimal alternative, while an xml drawable would.

Comment: I set background picture to my layout, so if I use setBackground to set xml for render rounded corners, background picture will disappear

Comment: Obviously, my friend. You can't set 2 backgrounds. The second one  replaces the first one. Now, if your picture is as simple as just a color spot, then you're lucky: use the xml drawable and that's all. Otherwise (a landscape, and object, a face, a texture, ...), you have to resort to something different, such as a LayerList. OR a round PNG.